# About memory leak

Tags: c

There are several functions in my c application which has memory leakage problems. But I do not call those functions(contains memory leak problem) rather call other functions for a specific task. Am I still in risk of memory leakage using this application?

Comment: Why don't you exclude those functions from compilation? A moderate compiler would do that anyway, but best to be sure, as they are known dead-codes.

Comment: If you don't call a function (directly or indirectly) then it won't run and nothing it does will happen.

Comment: No, but if the code is not called, why not ifdef it?

Comment: I can not exclude because those functions are in static library and some people use those functions for their purpose.

Comment: Why not just fix those functions?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have this piece of code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int allocate_mem()
{
    char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
}

int helloworld()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}

int main()
{
    helloworld();
    return 0;
}
```

In the above we haven't called the function that is allocating the memory, so there is no memory leak in the program as the function **allocate_mem()** is never called.

**update**:

some measures to avoid memory leak:

(1)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define KB (1024)

char *alloc_mem()
{
    char *mem = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1 * KB >>2);
    return mem;
}

int main()
{
    char *pmem = NULL;

    if(NULL == (pmem = alloc_mem()))
    {
        printf("err, failed when alloc_mem().\n");
        return -1; 
    }

    sprintf(pmem, "hello, world!\n");
    printf("%s", pmem);

    if(NULL != pmem)
        free(pmem);

    return 0;
}
```

(2)

```
int alloc_mem(char *pmem, long mem_sz)
{
    if(NULL == (pmem = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * mem_sz)))
    {
        printf("err, failed when malloc(), %s %s[%d].\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Calling `free(NULL);` is always safe, so that particular `if` is just noise.